# How to attack this problem with a volume that is hard to interpret / sketch,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Part 1

Show that the equation for the tangent plane to the ellipse $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1$ at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is given by $xx_0/a^2+yy_0b^2+zz_0c^2=1$ (*).

Part 2

Let $V(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ denote the volume bounded by the planes $x=0,y=0,z=0$ and the plane (*) for $x_0>0,y_0>0,z_0>0$. Find min$[V(x_0,y_0,z_0):x_0>0,y_0>0,z_0>0,(x_0,y_0,z_0)∈ellipse]$

I have solved Part 1 but am not sure how to start on Part 2.  The region is apparently a tetrahedron, but how could I have known that?  I don't even know how to begin sketching this volume out on paper.

Or, could I still get by and solve the Part 2 *without* knowing that the volume was a tetrahedron?

Any tips or comments are welcome.

Thanks,